# Nodejs: Getting average number of requests

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to send X requests to http://date.jsontest.com/ where X is an argument to my program. I've managed to get the latency for one request but now need to calculate the average time in milliseconds for multiple requests. I have an array `responseTimes[]` where I'd like to store the response times. How do I possibly add the multiple response times and get the average? Any help? Do I need to use the setTimeout function in the first place?

I'm using node v8.9.4 if fetchURL does not work on your end.

Here's my *code*

```
var fetchUrl = require("fetch").fetchUrl;

fetchUrl("http://date.jsontest.com", function(error, meta, body){

    const start = new Date();
    const responseTimes = [];
    let count = 0;

    setTimeout(function (argument) {
        // execution time simulated with setTimeout function
        var end = new Date() - start;
        console.log("Execution time: %dms", end);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing responseTime[] then with that you can store count of requests. So at any point in time, you can get average by the following function -

```
function getAvg(timeArr, count){
    let sum = 0;
    for(let i=0; i<timeArr.length; i++){
        sum += timeArr[i];
    }
    return sum/count;
}
```

Also, It's not necessary to store responseTime[]. You can just calculate avg on each request and store only the average and count If you just need average.

```
var fetchUrl = require("fetch").fetchUrl;
let responseTime = [];
let count = 0;
fetchUrl("http://date.jsontest.com", function(error, meta, body){
    const start = new Date();
    const requests = [];
    let count = 0;

    setTimeout(function (argument) {
        // execution time simulated with setTimeout function
        var end = new Date() - start;
        console.log("Execution time: %dms", end);
        responseTime.push(end);
        count++;
        let averageNow = getAvg(responseTime, count);
        console.log(averageNow);// this is your average

    });
});
```

Comment: Could you edit this please to include url fetch to help me understand clearly?

Comment: Are you able to test it out on your end? You  declared `count` twice and  and you do not use `requests[]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `start` variable outside the request.

```
var fetchUrl = require("fetch").fetchUrl;
var start = new Date();

fetchUrl("http://date.jsontest.com", function(error, meta, body){
    const requests = [];
    let count = 0;

    // execution time simulated with setTimeout function
    var end = new Date() - start;
    console.log("Execution time: %dms", end);
});
```

Comment: How do I collect all the average times in the `resquests[]` array?

Comment: Average time of what? That's only one request.

Comment: Post has been edited. See if you can understand what I'm trying to achieve. Is there a way I can create an array to store the response times and later get the average?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I've done. reponseTime can be accessed from outside so you can calculate average later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Artillery](https://artillery.io/docs/getting-started/) npm module to get the average response time of an API.